# Create new data Columns before union excel files

Tags: python

I repost this question about union excel. I know how to read data from excel. I just wondering is there a method I can union them automatically. And I did some google search. I cannot find the same situation as mine. That why I post the question. I do not know why my previous question closed? ???

I really appreciate your help!

---

I need to merge several excel files vertically. The files are in the same folder. They have the same columns. However, they don't have a 'Date' column, the date is on excel's name.

for example:

excel 1 named "items_03152021"
has cols:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

excel 2 named "items_03222021"
has cols:

```
a  b  c
2  2  3
3  5  6
```

.
.
.
excel 10 named "items_05172021"
has cols:

```
a  b  c
3  3  3
6  5  6
```

I need to make them like:

```
Date      a   b   c
03152021  1   2   3
03152021  4   5   6
03222021  2   2   3
03222021  3   5   6
.
.
.
05172021  3   3   3
05222021  6   5   6
```

Thank you very much!

JH

Here is the code I tried:

```
all_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'c:user\\' ):
    for x in files:
        if '.xlsx' in x:
            all_files.append(root + '\\' + x)
df1 = pd.read_excel([x for x in all_files if '0315' in x][0])
df1.loc[:,'Date'] = '03152021'
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')

df2 = pd.read_excel([x for x in all_files if '0322' in x][0])
df2.loc[:,'Date'] = '03222021'
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')
.
.
.
df10 = pd.read_excel([x for x in all_files if '0517' in x][0])
df10.loc[:,'Date'] = '05172021'
df10['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df10['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')

union = pd.concat([df1, df2, ..., df10], ignore_index=True)
```

I just read the excel manually and add the date columns. I am trying to find a way can do them automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in handling Excel files with the Pandas library, but I think I managed to automate the process:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dfList = []  #dataframe list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'c:user\\' ):
    excelFiles = (file for file in files if '.xlsx' in file) #generator expression with the files that ends with .xlsx

    for f in excelFiles:
        print(f)
        dateName = f.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1] #assuming that the pattern "+XXXX_[DateString].xlsx" will not be changed

        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root,f))
        df.loc[:,'Date'] = dateName
        df = df[['Date','a','b','c']] #change the order of columns
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%d%Y')

        dfList.append(df)

union = pd.concat(dfList,ignore_index=True)
print(union)
```

I did some tests with files that meet the parameters giving me these results:

```
file name: ea_05122021.xlsx
file name: eb_03152021.xlsx
file name: ec_03222021.xlsx
file name: xx_05172021.xlsx

        Date   a   b    c
0 2021-05-12   1   4    5
1 2021-05-12   2   3    6
2 2021-03-15   1   4    5
3 2021-03-15   2   3    6
4 2021-03-22   1   4   54
5 2021-03-22  43  12   55
6 2021-05-17  33  56  677
7 2021-05-17  65  76  998
```

I hope this answer helps you, also [here is the documentation about python generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)